# The requirement of compactness for the Strict Separation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

In class I learned about the following theorem:

**Strict Separation Theorem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be two closed convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Furthermore assume that $A$ is compact. Then $A$ and $B$ can be separated strongly, i.e., there is a $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$v^Ta \ge v^Tb + \epsilon \quad (\forall a \in A, \forall b \in B).$$

My question is: Why do we require compactness of $A$? Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the statement of the theorem says that $A$ should be compact, it's totally symmetric in $A$ and $B$, so any counterexample will require $A$ and $B$ *both* be noncompact.

But now, consider, for instance, the closed convex sets

$$A = \{ (x,y) \mid x \leq 0 \}$$

$$B = \{ (x,y) \mid xy \geq 1, x \geq 0 \}$$

shown in the picture below:

[image: two closed convex sets that get very close to each other]

Now, these sets are disjoint (since the $x$ coordinate in $B$ must always be *strictly* greater than $0$)
but you can easily see that they are *not* strongly separated.

Indeed, for any $\epsilon > 0$ and for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we can find $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ with
$v^T(b-a) < \epsilon$. This is intuitively clear, and I'll leave it as a fairly easy exercise to construct $a$ and $b$ from $v$ and $\epsilon$ if you want to. As a hint, notice that by taking the $x$ coordinates sufficiently small, we can make $\lVert b-a \rVert$ as small as we like.

---

I hope this helps ^_^